# Modifying javascript table to search for specific data

Tags: javascript, html

The search form I'm using is found here: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/js-table-filter-simple-insensitive

I found a nice js search form created by Cyruxx that I am implementing on my site. Is it possible to modify this code to only search specific table headers?

For example I have:

```
     <table class="table table-list-search">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>id</th>
                        <th>name</th>
                        <th>address</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>107</td>
                        <td>John Doe</td>
                        <td>1074 example street</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>100</td>
                        <td>Henry</td>
                        <td>1111 example ave</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

How can I modify the code to only search the id column for example. In other words, typing the number '1' would only show table rows with a '1' in the 'id' header. Typing '1074' in my example would return 0 results while typing '1' would show both listings.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var activeSystemClass = $('.list-group-item.active');

    //something is entered in search form
    $('#system-search').keyup( function() {
       var that = this;
        // affect all table rows on in systems table
        var tableBody = $('.table-list-search tbody');
        var tableRowsClass = $('.table-list-search tbody tr');
        $('.search-sf').remove();
        tableRowsClass.each( function(i, val) {

            //Lower text for case insensitive
            var rowText = $(val).text().toLowerCase();
            var inputText = $(that).val().toLowerCase();
            if(inputText != '')
            {
                $('.search-query-sf').remove();
                tableBody.prepend('<tr class="search-query-sf"><td colspan="6"><strong>Searching for: "'
                    + $(that).val()
                    + '"</strong></td></tr>');
            }
            else
            {
                $('.search-query-sf').remove();
            }

            if( rowText.indexOf( inputText ) == -1 )
            {
                //hide rows
                tableRowsClass.eq(i).hide();

            }
            else
            {
                $('.search-sf').remove();
                tableRowsClass.eq(i).show();
            }
        });
        //all tr elements are hidden
        if(tableRowsClass.children(':visible').length == 0)
        {
            tableBody.append('<tr class="search-sf"><td class="text-muted" colspan="6">No entries found.</td></tr>');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - that's not great search code, its not terribly preformant and mixes view and model concerns in a way that might get difficult to maintain. I would recommend using a pre-build widget, rather than copy-pasting code that you don't understand from blogs (or wherever).

To answer your question though, you can simply constrain which columns are searchable with a css class, and use that class as a search filter:

so change

```
var rowText = $(val).text().toLowerCase();
```

to

```
var rowText = $(val).find('.searchable').text().toLowerCase();
```

and then tag everything that you want to be searchable:

```
 <table class="table table-list-search">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>name</th>
                    <th>address</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="searchable">107</td>
                    <td>John Doe</td>
                    <td>1074 example street</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="searchable">100</td>
                    <td>Henry</td>
                    <td>1111 example ave</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: Thanks George, I understand it is bad practice to use code snippets off internet but I am not skilled in JS at the moment. I want to now add a checkbox / dropdown menu which would allow the viewer to search by different table headers of their choice(search by: 'id' or 'name' or 'email' or 'all'). Should I be adding this box to the search function itself? or elsewhere?

Comment: @RyanGoo I understand your position, but please be aware of the sacrifices you make. When you do things like this it is very possible to expose security holes (though I don't think you do in the above case) and incredibly likely you will be throwing all the code out multiple times. There are good alternatives however, you can try to use a pre-build table widget with searchable functionality. For example [datatables](http://datatables.net/) though there are many possible. You could also write something that works and post it on  codreview.stackexchange.com for comment.

Comment: To answer your specific question, if you do it the way that I recommend, you could hook up a handler to the selector/checkbox that on selection does `allRows.find('td').removeClass('.selectable')` allRows.find('.'+desiredColumn).addClass('.selectable')`